# Angular app "Please add a @NgModule annotation"

Tags: angular, pdfmake

I'm trying to use PdfMake in an Angular app while following this guide: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pdf-make and I can't seem to get it to work.
This is the content of my app.module.ts:

```
// other imports are here
import { PdfmakeModule } from 'ng-pdf-make'; // edited

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    InvalidRequestComponent,
    LoadingComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    PdfmakeModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The error I get is:

```
"Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'PdfmakeModule' imported by the 
module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation."
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That package has its own version of node_modules with @angular packages. Angular library has to exclude it from package because angular compiler matches having annotations by using `instanceOf`

Comment: The import instruction is pretty clear, why are you importing the PdfmakeModule from other path?

Comment: change the first line to import { PdfmakeModule } from 'ng-pdf-make';

Comment: I forgot to change the first line back when I copied the code here, but it used to be "import { PdfmakeModule } from 'ng-pdf-make';" and I still got the exact same error.
@yurzui - I found some links saying to delete the node_modules from pdfmake and change tsconfig.json, but that also didn't work.